# phantomjs not loading static assets

Tags: django, phantomjs

Am attempting to [rasterize](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) a page served by Django. It appears that only the base html as returned by the Django template engine is being rendered by the rasterize script.

Heres it the http traffic during a request:

```
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/login/?next=/application/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4159
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/static/css/footer.css HTTP/1.1" 200 841
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 506
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/static/js/stupidtable.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5402
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 11923
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/static/js/g.raphael.js HTTP/1.1" 200 27680
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:15] "GET /application/static/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3117
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:16] "GET /application/static/js/chart.raphael.js HTTP/1.1" 200 39384
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:16] "GET /application/static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 200 61752
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:16] "GET /application/static/js/raphael.js HTTP/1.1" 200 226951
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:16] "GET /application/static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 127407
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:16] "GET /application/static/js/jquery1.9.js HTTP/1.1" 200 342486
[19/Dec/2013 12:44:16] "GET /application/static/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 15012
```

Phantomjs is executed as:

```
phantomjs ~/rasterize.js 'http://localhost:8000/application' g.pdf
```

The resulting pdf contains unstyle HTML.

Update: html is rendered correctly when I specify a file extension other than *pdf.

```
phantomjs ~/rasterize.js 'http://localhost:8000/application' g.png
```

Returns correct rendering.

Comment: The rasterize.js example contains a timeout of 200ms, after which the page is rendered. Did you try to increase the timeout?

Comment: @sk1p I set the timeout to 20000 and received the same result. TYA